# SQL or NoSQL for survey application tool

Tags: sql, mongodb, web, relational-database, nosql

I am designing a survey tool which users can use to build their surveys or polls etc. So a basic survey tool needs to allow users to design a questions , upload files , login , register , share the survey, notify and set activation of survey constraints.

I did some study to take decision to use which kind of database at backend, either sql or nosql. 
I have experience of designing only Relational database so I a unable to take into consideration IF Mongo DB or some other Nosql database will satisfy my Web tool requirements.

Please give me suggestion along with reason how to select database type for my Web tool.

Thanks

Comment: Select one that you know how to work with.

Comment: Your application can be written using either. So ask yourself this question: Is now the right time to learn a new technology, with the extra time consumption that this entails, or would you rather finish quicker by leveraging the knowledge you already have?

Answer (score 5):

If you have time to learn new technology I suggest you to choose Nosql database. I prefer MongoDB but you can choose any other. In survey application, each survey will have different fields and it will be hard to handle it using Relational database. Schema-free database will help you to handle it easily.